# Any impact of upgrade db2 from V10.5 to V11.5?

Tags: db2, upgrade

Good day,

Due to the `DB2 v10.5` will end of support on next year April. I would like to change my application database version to `v11.5`.

Before apply this to production, I do it in my local VM first. The following are the steps I have done:

1. backup original database.
2. Install `DB2 v11.5`, because its same environment, do I cant have same user call `db2inst1`, so I create another instance call `db2inst2`.
3. log in as `db2inst2`, run restore command to restore the image file I done in step 1 :

   db2 restore database mydb from /home/db2inst2 on /home/db2inst2

After this, I configure my Jboss server to point to this new database, application can log in and working fine.

I am thinking that, is there anything I need to take care? or anything I need to avoid ? I am worry that there are something issue unforeseen will happen.

Comment: The manual covers the upgrade procedure pretty nicely; anything there that doesn't seem clear?

Answer (score 0):

If you will need a Solaris Client, you won't get a client for the last version. IBM drop the support for Db2 in that platform.

Remember to rebind packages.

Also, update Db2 clients and JDBC clients to have everything in the same version.